# How to import a private repository into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github

Using eclipse Neon with the egit plugin, there is an option to import a repository from github-- but this seems to only search public repositories, and I don't see a way to configure eclipse with my github account information.

Is there a way to configure eclipse to be able to import from a private github repository?  Or do I just need to check the repository out myself first outside of eclipse, and then import that?  Is there some github integration that I would loose by doing it this way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [SSH configuration](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Eclipse_SSH_Configuration) in which you setup your ssh key registered to your account.

Since your account has access to your private repo, Eclipse will be able to clone/fetch it.

Comment: SSH configuration is already set up by default, and I've added my key to my profile, but for some reason it does not seem to see it...